# Load WSDL failed

Tags: php, wsdl

I tried to load WSDL like this :

```
Base_DigiDoc::load_WSDL();
$dd = new Base_DigiDoc();
```

My WSDL file name is : **wsdl.class.php**

and I get error,

```
 Strict standards: Non-static method Base_DigiDoc::load_WSDL() should not be called statically in C:\wamp\www\source\auth_sample\index.php on line 11
```

Im doing something wrong or  ... ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: `Base_DigiDoc::load_WSDL();`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$dd = new Base_DigiDoc();
$dd->load_WSDL();
```